# Как передать шаблон функции в другую функцию?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++14

Как правильно написать функцию `test`, чтобы ей в качестве аргумента (либо шаблонного параметра - не важно) можно было передать любую из функций `f` и `g`, с возможностью их вызова с разным типом аргумента (в примере int, char и long).

http://ideone.com/1aZ8Zu

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> auto f(T x) -> decltype(x*x)
{
  return x * x;
}

template <typename T> T g(T x)
{
  return x * x;
}

template <template <class> class F> void test(F f)
{
    auto a = f(32);
    auto b = f(' ');
    auto c = f(2000000000L);

    cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(f);
    test(g);

    return 0;
}
```

Этот код не компилируется с сообщениями:

```
prog.cpp:15:47: error: variable or field 'test' declared void
 template <template <class> class F> void test(F f)
                                               ^
prog.cpp:15:49: error: missing template arguments before 'f'
 template <template <class> class F> void test(F f)
                                                 ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:26:8: error: 'test' was not declared in this scope
  test(f);
        ^
```

Comment: Связанный [ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437571/178988), который мне не помог.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Могу порекомендовать в определенном смысле обходной, но в определенном - и прямой путь. В C++14 (а у вас четко указан этот тэг) лямбды тоже могут быть шаблонами.

```
auto f = [](auto x){ cout << x << endl; return x*x; };

template<typename F> void test(F f)
{
    auto a = f(32);
    auto b = f(' ');
    auto c = f(2000000000ull);

    cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Вызывается `f` именно как шаблон (разная для разных аргументов).

Да, это не есть абсолютно строгий и точный ответ на заданный вопрос, но - шаблон в шаблоне вызван :)

Можно использовать лямбду и как уровень косвенности:

```
template <typename T> T g_(T x)
{
  return x * x * x;
}

auto g = [](auto x){ cout << typeid(x).name() << endl; return g_(x); };

template<typename F> void test(F f)
{
    auto a = f(32);
    auto b = f(' ');
    auto c = f(2000000000ull);
    cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(g);

    return 0;
}
```

Пример на ideone: http://ideone.com/kfUWtx

Answer (score 5):

Немного теории.

Для того, чтобы можно было вызывать `f(42)` и `f(42L)` одновременно - переменная `f` должна быть типа, у которого определен шаблонный оператор `()`:

```
struct F {
  template <typename T> void operator () (T value);
};

void test(F f); // работает
```

Если же переставить шаблон в другое место - то вы не сможете инстанцировать `F`:

```
template <typename T> struct F {
  void operator () (T value);
};

void test(F f); // ошибка компиляции: F - это шаблон типа, а не тип
```

Проблема с функциями - в том, что ссылка на шаблонную функцию больше похожа по своим свойствам на вторую форму записи, чем на первую.

Как уже [написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585252/178779) [@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) - для неявного создания структуры первого типа можно использовать лябмды:

```
auto g = [](auto x){ return x*x; };

template<typename F> test(F f); // сюда можно передать переменную g
```

Comment: Не обязательно иметь шаблонный `operator()`, можно и [конструктор](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yjhn2mvlLQP6UeOB).

Comment: @alexolut я рассматриваю f - как переменную некоторого типа, а не тип сам по себе. Очевидно, что тип с шаблонным конструктором передать в функцию по значению не получится.

Comment: Тогда, имхо, есть смысл добавить после `одновременно`: `из функции, которая принимает переменную f`. Чтобы предложение было самодостаточным. Хотя, согласен, что контекст тут тоже надо иметь в виду.

Comment: @alexolut, использование конструктора, в таком контексте, противоречит его семантике. В C++ принято использовать `operator()()` для подобных целей.

Comment: @ixSci я исходил из требования самодостаточности предложения, поэтому и привел такой пример.

Comment: Кстати, после замены generic-лямбды на класс с шаблонным `operator()` код будет удовлетворять `c++11`, а не только `c++14`.

Comment: @alexolut, если заменить, то он будет удовлетворять С++98

Comment: @ixSci там еще вопрос с возвращаемым типом. Придется использовать trail-return-type

Comment: @alexolut, ага, упустил этот момент

Comment: [`test([](auto x) { return f(x); });`](http://ideone.com/F8bJ5c) действительно получается. Но как бы вызывающий код от этого избавить?

Comment: @Qwertiy макрос :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, макросы-то от всего помогают. Хоть сам `test` макросом сделать. Через шаблоны интереснее.

Answer (score 3):

Это невозможно, в том виде, что Вы хотите. Вы имеете две шаблонных функции `test` и `f`, которые встречаются в одном выражении, и в которых тип аргумента должен быть выведен из переданных аргументов. Что может вывести из этой `test(f)` строчки компилятор? Ничего, т.к. нет никакой уточняющей информации, конкретизирующей, что за версию нужно инстанциировать.

Comment: Меня и `test<f>()` устроит, но тоже не получается :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, Вы ничего не изменили и не добавили — ни `f` ни `test` здесь не стали конкретными.